# Rails: couldn't find file 'typeahead.js'.. until i remove 'data-turbolinks'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, typeahead.js

I installed Elasticsearch (with searchkick gem) following this tutorial - https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/adding-search-and-autocomplete-to-a-rails-app-with-elasticsearch.

Search is working and now I'm implementing autocomplete function with typeahead.js which I installed using Bower.
However I get the error message:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound at /books couldn't find file 'typeahead.js'
```

I tried to include it in various orders in my assets file, without luck..
However I realized removing turbolinks from application.html.erb solved the problem.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

This does not seem right... How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. The author named the library with the .js extension added and I assume it has something to do with application.js ignoring the .js part at the end. I had this problem when using [rails-assets](https://rails-assets.org/) and once I poked around more in the gem source I saw two .js.js extensions added.

You can add it as so:

```
//= require typeahead.js.js
```

Then you can re-enable

```
'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```